# Questions about the formrecognizer function of azure

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

[image: Capture]

When Microsoft azure is used for table recognition, the characters in the table are Chinese characters. Can the table recognition function work normally？The specific function used is recognize content.Looking forward to your answers

Comment: You should add more details about your issue, and what you have done so far. What do you mean by "the characters in the table are Chinese characters": you got a chinese output? Or is it your input file which contains these Chinese characters?

Comment: Yes, my input test picture contain Chinese characters. I found that the test results did not meet expectations.When the test image contains only English characters and Arabic numerals, Identification results meet expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer is currently valid for:

- English sales receipts with the prebuilt "Receipts" model (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/overview#prebuilt-receipt-model?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365))
- Latin alphabet for custom models (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/overview#custom-model?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365))

So it's a current limitation of the product as it is quite new.

Comment: Maybe they are all available now? See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/language-support)

Comment: Yes it has been released with 2.1 preview, in August 2020 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/form-recognizer-v2-1/

Answer (score 0):

The support for Chinese and other language in Form Recognizer will come in future releases.

Comment: Maybe they are all available now? See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/language-support)